# ZFS, Ubuntu 18.04 - Loss of recently written data

Tags: data-recovery, zfs, data-loss, user-data

I have some audio files that are copied to a ZFS filesystem, but after opening most them with VLC for a few minutes, Files and VLC crashed, and I am left with none of the audio files in the directory.

I realized that scrubbing was taking place when this has happened, and I have another user session in the background. After the failure, the RAM usage has apparently reached its limit in RAM (10.xGB out of 16GB), checked from GNOME system monitor.

The pool is a RAIDZ2 pool, and it is only storing data. The pool is called "data", the volume is "wood". Ubuntu 18.04 is on a separate single disk. As a side note, I don't have a swap partition.

The machine serves as a NAS and a desktop computer. It has 4 x 2TB WD Red HDDs, 16GB ECC unbuffered RAM.

Here is the output of `apt list --installed *zfs*`:

```
    Listing... Done
    libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-zfs/bionic-updates,now 4.0.0-1ubuntu8.5 amd64 [installed]
    libzfs2linux/bionic-updates,now 0.7.5-1ubuntu16.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    zfs-auto-snapshot/bionic,bionic,now 1.2.4-1 all [installed]
    zfs-dkms/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 0.7.5-1ubuntu16.4 all [installed]
    zfs-zed/bionic-updates,now 0.7.5-1ubuntu16.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
    zfsutils-linux/bionic-updates,now 0.7.5-1ubuntu16.4 amd64 [installed]
```

Here is the output of `uname -srvp`:

`Linux 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64`

Here is the output of `zfs get all data/wood`:

```
    NAME       PROPERTY              VALUE                  SOURCE
    data/wood  type                  filesystem             -
    data/wood  creation              Tue Oct  2 20:18 2018  -
    data/wood  used                  92.8G                  -
    data/wood  available             2.41T                  -
    data/wood  referenced            92.4G                  -
    data/wood  compressratio         1.06x                  -
    data/wood  mounted               yes                    -
    data/wood  quota                 none                   default
    data/wood  reservation           none                   default
    data/wood  recordsize            128K                   default
    data/wood  mountpoint            /home/wood             inherited from data
    data/wood  sharenfs              off                    default
    data/wood  checksum              on                     default
    data/wood  compression           lz4                    inherited from data
    data/wood  atime                 off                    inherited from data
    data/wood  devices               on                     default
    data/wood  exec                  on                     default
    data/wood  setuid                on                     default
    data/wood  readonly              off                    default
    data/wood  zoned                 off                    default
    data/wood  snapdir               hidden                 default
    data/wood  aclinherit            restricted             default
    data/wood  createtxg             31                     -
    data/wood  canmount              on                     default
    data/wood  xattr                 on                     default
    data/wood  copies                1                      default
    data/wood  version               5                      -
    data/wood  utf8only              off                    -
    data/wood  normalization         none                   -
    data/wood  casesensitivity       sensitive              -
    data/wood  vscan                 off                    default
    data/wood  nbmand                off                    default
    data/wood  sharesmb              off                    default
    data/wood  refquota              none                   default
    data/wood  refreservation        none                   default
    data/wood  guid                  11841622045429837125   -
    data/wood  primarycache          all                    default
    data/wood  secondarycache        all                    default
    data/wood  usedbysnapshots       418M                   -
    data/wood  usedbydataset         92.4G                  -
    data/wood  usedbychildren        0B                     -
    data/wood  usedbyrefreservation  0B                     -
    data/wood  logbias               latency                default
    data/wood  dedup                 off                    default
    data/wood  mlslabel              none                   default
    data/wood  sync                  standard               default
    data/wood  dnodesize             legacy                 default
    data/wood  refcompressratio      1.06x                  -
    data/wood  written               5.73M                  -
    data/wood  logicalused           98.8G                  -
    data/wood  logicalreferenced     98.3G                  -
    data/wood  volmode               default                default
    data/wood  filesystem_limit      none                   default
    data/wood  snapshot_limit        none                   default
    data/wood  filesystem_count      none                   default
    data/wood  snapshot_count        none                   default
    data/wood  snapdev               hidden                 default
    data/wood  acltype               off                    default
    data/wood  context               none                   default
    data/wood  fscontext             none                   default
    data/wood  defcontext            none                   default
    data/wood  rootcontext           none                   default
    data/wood  relatime              off                    default
    data/wood  redundant_metadata    all                    default
    data/wood  overlay               off                    default
```

Do I have any luck recovering the files?

Comment: Scrub doesn't delete files, it just detects and fixes checksum errors. Since nothing else appears to be broken, my guess is that VLC deleted the files, rather than something inside ZFS. Unless you have a snapshot of that filesystem where the files reside, I don't think you will be able to recover them.

Comment: What does ZoL do when the cache in RAM is full and don’t have storage to swap with? Could it be that data (or metadata) in RAM simply got truncated?

Comment: Nope, ZFS only caches data that is also written to disk. When it has to evict from the cache to free up space, the data is already on disk, so it is always safe to do so.